# JWPlayer Choppy Video Because of Ajax Requests

Tags: ajax, jwplayer

I am having an issue while playing video through jwplayer. At first i thought the issue might be the streaming servers i am using but when i copied the stream URL into chrome or VLC it worked fine. Then i did not thinking and say that I have a lot of ajax requests (setTimeouts) running and wanted to see if this was the cause for the choppy video playback. I disabled all the ajax requests and the video plays fine when no ajax requests are running.

One thing i could do is cut down on the ajax requests, but I was wondering if anyone else had a similar issue and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem was those ajax requests were synchronous but should be async.